# Best way to keep a React app updated on a linux server

Tags: reactjs, github, server, web-hosting, ubuntu-20.04

I am currently in college and am creating a portfolio website on my own to set myself apart from other students. I have set up a home Linux server and have hosted a personal website on it.

The issue I'm running into is having to constantly update the website with demos of new projects I've completed. I want to be able to do something like pushing new projects or updates to old projects to GitHub and be able to simply pull the updated repository to my server without having to delete the old project and build the new one on the server over and over.

Is there a best practice for this and does anyone have a good guide or documentation I can follow to figure this out? I know I can simply use hosting services that are drag and drop every time i update the code however I enjoy the complexity of running my own server and figuring out these issues.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks